# Chatmessage schema with Supabase

Tags: postgresql, chat, supabase

I have created a project for a chat app with Supabase and want to query every chatroom a user is in.

My database schema looks similar to this example:
https://medium.com/@mutationevent/mysql-schema-for-a-chat-application-7e0067dd04fd

What is the best way to query every chatroom of a user?

I already tried to query it with a database function, but I don't know if this is the most efficient way and it feels to the API quite limited.
Here is the code for that.

```
select
  cr.id as chatroom_id,
  cr.name as chatroom_name,
  cu.user_name as other_user_name,
  cr.created_at as chatroom_created_at
from
  chatrooms cr
  join chatroom_users cu on cr.id = cu.room_id
where
  cu.user_id = userid;
```

Does anyone has suggestions or experience to query something with the supabase API on the client side? What is the best way to do that and which RLS should be made?

Comment: You can set RLS policy so that each users can only read chat rooms that they are a part of. With that setup, you can just query all chat rooms from the client, and Supabase will automatically filter the returned results to those that the user has permission to view. This is a Flutter example, but you can just read the SQL part of it. https://supabase.com/blog/flutter-authorization-with-rls